# How to update user data with uid in firestore in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am working on a project in which I have stored user data in Fire store with name, email and user role, here is the screenshot of this and user role is defined as basic.[check it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wqin.jpg)

Now here my auth service code in flutter

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class GSignInhelp {
 static FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

static signInWithGoogle() async {
GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final account = await googleSignIn.signIn();
final auth = await account.authentication;
final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
  accessToken: auth.accessToken,
  idToken: auth.idToken,
);
final res = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
return res.user;
}

static logOut(){
GoogleSignIn().signOut();
return _auth.signOut();
}

}

String role = 'basic';

class Usertype {
static FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

static saveUser(User user) async {
 Map<String,dynamic> userData = {
  'name': user.displayName,
  'email': user.email,
  'role' : role,
 };

final userRef = _db.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
if((await userRef.get()).exists){
  get('role');
  userData.update('role', (value) => role);
}else{
  await userRef.set(userData);
}

}
}
```

and I want to update user role when user make a successful payment here I am using Razor pay and code for it is here

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_razorpay =Razorpay();
_razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_SUCCESS, _handlePaymentSuccess);
_razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_ERROR, _handlePaymentError);
_razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_EXTERNAL_WALLET, _handleExternalWallet);
}

@override
void dispose() {
// TODO: implement dispose
super.dispose();
_razorpay.clear();
 }

 void openCheckout() async{
   var option= {
     "key": "rzp_test_rkbMfLcwVZtwyk",
     'amount': _paymentamount*100,
    'name': 'ghori fashion designer',
    'description': 'expert bane',
    'prefill' : {
    'contact' : '1234567890',
    'email' : 'anything@gmail.com',
   },
    'external' : {
    'wallet' : ['paytm']
  }
  };
  try{
  _razorpay.open(option);
  }
  catch(e){
  debugPrint(e);
  }
  }

 void _handlePaymentSuccess(PaymentSuccessResponse response){
 Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "SUCCESS: "+ response.paymentId);
 setState(() {
  role = 'fullexpert';
 });
 }

 void _handlePaymentError(PaymentFailureResponse response){
 Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Error: "+ response.code.toString() + ' - ' + response.message);
 }

void _handleExternalWallet(ExternalWalletResponse response){
Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "External Wallet: "+ response.walletName);
}
```

and this is main activity code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gfd_official/Login_data/Login.dart';
import 'package:gfd_official/Login_data/gSignin_data.dart';
import 'package:gfd_official/Mainhome.dart';
import 'package:gfd_official/paid_screens/Expert1year.dart';

void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await Firebase.initializeApp();
 runApp(MyApp());
 }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
  title: 'ghori fashion designer',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: MySplashScreen(),
 );
}
}

class MySplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_MySplashScreenState createState() => _MySplashScreenState();
}

// ignore: camel_case_types
class _MySplashScreenState extends State<MySplashScreen> {
@override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
Future.delayed(
    Duration(
      seconds: 3,
    ),
        () {});
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
      Usertype.saveUser(snapshot.data);
      return StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(
              snapshot.data.uid).snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
              final user = snapshot.data.data();
              if(user['role'] == 'fullexpert'){
                return Expert1year();
              }else{
                return Mainhome();
              }
            }
            return Material(
              child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),),);
          });
    }
    return Loginpage();
  },
);
}
}
```

**when I run the app and make payment after success payment nothing happens and when I logout and login again role changes in Firestore but I have noticed some weird when I have made payment with an account and logged out and I just signed in with different account role for user who just logged in have changed but not for user who have made payment.**

One more issue I got that the role changes for only onw time next time user login in the role again become ***basic*** instead of ***fullexpert***

I have google searched it but due big change in firebase with flutter in 2020 all methods are not applicable.

Please if someone can help me to how can I **change user role with user unique id or UID** and this **change remain until user upgrade role or downgrade role and it should be for specific user**.

Comment: Try using the provider package. Setup your listeners in the provider and notify changes after saving the new values to a public variable.

Comment: @BrandonPillay can you please explain it

Comment: Where is _handlePaymentSuccess being called from?

Comment: @BrandonPillay I am using Razorpay payment gateaway it gives us this functions for success, failure and external wallet.

Comment: @BrandonPillay not worked nothing happens after payment even done in not printed please also upvote it so that it can reach more people

Comment: @BrandonPillay what is your other advice

Answer (score 0):

When _handlePaymentSuccess is called it updates the state value `role`, but `role` isn't referenced in your  *user document streambuilder* try this:

**UNTESTED**

SuccessHandler(Updated):

```
 void _handlePaymentSuccess(PaymentSuccessResponse response){
     Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "SUCCESS: "+ response.paymentId);
     //Update the User role directly from here. When this is called the streambuilder will 
     //refesh. 
     userRef.update({'role': 'fullexpert'}).then((value) => print('Done!'));
     //setState(() {
      //role = 'fullexpert';
     //});
     }






 //String role = 'basic';
 DocumentReference userRef;

 class Usertype {
 static FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
 
 static saveUser(User user) async {
  Map<String,dynamic> userData = {
   'name': user.displayName,
   'email': user.email,
   'role' : role,
  };

 userRef = _db.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
  if((await userRef.get()).exists){
   //Try removing this as it redundant: 
   //get('role');//???
   //userData.update('role', (value) => role);
  }else{
   await userRef.set(userData);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: not worked nothing happens after payment even done in not printed please also upvote it so that it can reach more people

Comment: Are the roles still changing with you log in and out?

Comment: Do you see the success toast message?

Comment: Then that means the success handler wasn't called. The issue is with the payment API.

Comment: Which Razor pay package are you using?

Comment: may be because in DocumentReference userRef ;                                                  
userRef is not linked to userRef down

Comment: payment api is fine it is shown success in razorpay dashboard

Comment: sorry for delay but i was just uploading it here is the link (https://github.com/yashir5686/ghori-fashion-designer)

Comment: Are you sure you're seeing this toast:  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "SUCCESS: "+ response.paymentId); ?

Comment: I am getting this toast but not getting the role changes

Comment: I have other recommendations but try removing the final declaration from : final user = snapshot.data.data(); in the second streambuilder listener.

Comment: when I am removing it i am getting error in determining user role to switch to screens if(user['role'] == 'fullexpert'){
                    return Expert1year();
                  }else{
                    return Mainhome();
                  }
                }                                                                                                                                                      I am getting error in user

Comment: what's is your other recommendation

Comment: I have tried but nothing working what's your other recommendation I will also try it.